# Restoring a dokuwki to openshift

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I have an openshift account with dokuwiki in one app php 5.3 cartige, I do backups using rhc snapshot save every day, today I try to do a restore it with rhc snapshot restore, but it looks like data is from the last git push what I did and the changes which I did into the dokuwiki aren´t into the restored "snapshot".
am I doing something wrong? , 
Rhc command help displays snapshot saves "the state of the application", doesn´t it mean what I expect (save the whole state of application)? 
Thanks :)

OpenShift offers functionality to backup and restore with the snapshot command within the rhc client tools.
To backup your application code, data, logs and configuration, you run:

> rhc snapshot save -a {appName}
>   To restore your application, you run:
>   rhc snapshot restore -a {appName} -f {/path/to/snapshot/appName.tar.gz}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do an rhc snapshot save, it saves what is in your git repository, what is in your app-root/data, and what is in any databases that you have running.  So if you have ssh'd or sftp'd into your application and made changes, or used a web editor to make physical file changes (ones not stored in a database), then those changes will not be reflected in the backup/restore procedure.

Comment: You are right but the description of the help file is a little bit confusing at least to me